# Integrating $\cos^nx$ for all real values of $n$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I found this problem in a textbook and managed to solve it with a reduction formula
$$
\int_0^5\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x\overset{5\cos u=x}{=}5^n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}2}\cos^nu\mathrm{d}u
$$
However this supposes $n\in\mathbb{N}$. I wanted to generalise the problem for $n\in\mathbb{R}$ meaning the reduction formula can't be used. I've tried several approaches (using $\cos z=\cosh iz$ giving a complex result, series approximations, and even looked into polynomial rings) but to no avail. If it's of any help (probably a cardinal sin of maths) I checked WolframAlpha which gave
$$
\int_0^5\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{25-x^2}}\mathrm{d}x=\frac{5^n\sqrt{\pi}\;\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)}{n\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)}
$$
If anyone has any ideas on ways to go about solving this it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals and http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E2

Comment: @Gary thanks. not entirely sure how I managed not to find that before

Comment: You can also use beta function after the substitution $x^2=25t$.

Comment: What is the text book that you found this in ?